# Rviz click tool to set exploration boundary

Tags: ros, rviz, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying use the `frontier_exploration` node as documented on the ros wiki (note: I had a link to the wiki but couldn't post due to a lack of karma points). I have set everything up as per the instructions and have enabled visualization with a marker display in rviz. The wiki then say to:

> use the "Click Point" tool to mark the exploration boundary.

It is at this point that I have come unstuck. It feels like a stupid question but I can't seem to find any documentation telling me how to select these points. The RViz User Guide doesn't seem to say anything on the matter. The closest that I can see is that it says that the  **Select** tool supports single-point selection, but doesn't seem to offer any hint on how to use it. In any case it is not that clear that the **Select** tool is the right one.

The other rviz tools that I have are: Interact, Move Camera, Select, Focus Camera, Measure, 2D Pose Estimation, 2D Nav Goal, and Publish Point. I have tried various mouse clicking combinations with all these tools but nothing seems to do what I want. Maybe there some extra plugin package that I need to have installed?

In short, can anyone point me to instructions on how to set the frontier exploration boundary in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174957/rviz-click-tool-to-set-exploration-boundary/) by [DaveR](https://answers.ros.org/users/490/daver/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question...

You need to use the "Publish Point" tool to define the points in the polygon. This tool publishes on the `/clicked_point` topic. The display of these points, connected as a polygon, is via the "Marker" display that is subscribing to the `/exploration_polygon_marker` topic. Once the polygon loop has been closed, then it is necessary to also select a point within the polygon from which to start the exploration. Only then will the exploration start.

The `explore_client` node actually generates messages that are printed to the ROS log to first ask the user to define the polygon and then to ask for a point within the polygon. However, because my setup was generating lots of ROS warning messages (for an unrelated matter) I was missing these instructions.

---

Originally posted by [DaveR](https://answers.ros.org/users/490/daver/) with karma: 126 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-07-29**:
I updated the wiki to prevent similar frustrations for other people, thanks a lot for providing feedback!

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-08-28**:
what do you mean by "select a point within the polygon" ? stuck here

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-29**:
After you select the polygon boundary, you will be asked to select a point inside the boundary, which will be the starting-off point for the exploration task.

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-09-02**:
I figure that would be it but im clicking points inside the polygon boundary and nothing is happening. do i use the interact tool? select tool?

edit: need to use the publish point tool again to select a point. new errors are coming out on the terminal but nothing related to frontier_exploration. ty

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-03**:
I have the same problem. I am able to send the explore command using the publish points inside the polygon. Isn't there a simple method just to draw a rectangle since clicking and publishing points every time  is really cumbersome.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-12-04**:
Clicking on points is the only 'built in' way to draw a rectangle in rviz. Any improvements/constructive ideas are appreciated, please open issue/pull on the repo.